# objective-c: Siri on custom keyboard / input view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

currently i am working on a custom keyboard for my iphone app.

I'd like to add a button for the siri dictating functionality similar to the button in the default keyboard.

But how do i call the standard "siri/dictation functionality"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no public documented mechanism to do this.